# how to keep internet explorer video tag controls from disappearing a few seconds after mouse-out event?

Tags: internet-explorer, video, html5-video

The control panel at the bottom of the video element (html video tag) appears only when the mouse is over the element and fades shortly after.

I have not been able to find the attribute or other obvious setting that one would imagine is present to de-activate this unique behavior, not found in other browsers.

If no such option is available, what would be a good workaround?